# what is the keyboard shortcut to quit vscode?

Tags: shortcut-keys

What is the keyboard shortcut to quit vscode without closing the windows?
(same behaviour as clicking on "Visual Studio Code / Quit" in the menu bar)

Answer (score 0):

There is no such a shortcut for quick exit in the vscode in linux. Most closest thing is press CTRL-ALT-T for the new terminal and write pkill to quit fastly from vscode or just use ALT-F4. If you want to learn more about vscode shortcuts in linux, I am sharing the official documentation link:

https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-linux.pdf

Comment: won't Alt+F4 and `pkill` close the windows too (what OP said they don't want?) I might be misunderstanding the question...